# Combine multiple filters in RethinkDB and merge results from each filter with a ranking field

Tags: python, rethinkdb

Okay, say I have the following list:

```
[(('a', 'b', 'c'), 1), (('a', 'c'), 2), (('b'), 3)]
```

This list is composed of 3 tuples, each having 2 elements: a filter and a ranking. I would like to create a ReQL query, dynamically, that filters a table for each filter from the above list (using `has_fields`), and then adds a new field, `ranking: [n]`, when `n` is the ranking from the above list.

To get the idea, here's how I would do it with multiple queries:

```
for filters, ranking in list_:
    r.table(...).filter(lambda doc: doc.has_fields(*filters)).map(lambda doc: doc.merge({'ranking': ranking})).run(...)
```

I would like to merge the above queries into a single one, to minimize interaction with the database. Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

- Use `concatMap` for combining your queries
- Replace python splats such as `*filter` with `r.args(filter)`
- Simplify `.filter(lambda x: x.has_fields(...))` to just `.has_fields(...)`
- Same for `map` and `merge`

The code would look something like this:

```
 (r.expr(list_)
   .concatMap(lambda filts_rank:
      r.table(...)
       .has_fields(r.args(filts_rank[0]))
       .merge({'ranking': filts_rank[1]}))
 ).run(...)
```

Note that if you have duplicate keys in `list_`, some documents from the table may be returned multiple times, each with a different ranking.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's exactly what I've needed :) If it will be the case that duplicates are returned, how should I eliminate them?

Comment: You can use the `.distinct` method to only eliminate duplicates. http://rethinkdb.com/api/python/#distinct

Comment: `distinct` will not work in this case, because each duplicate document will have a different `ranking`.